# Is it possible to provide both oauth & basic username password log in option to a spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, google-oauth

I am trying to implement a basic login page with spring boot by providing both username & password based login as well google oAuth for user authentication.

Wondering if spring allows this to be done with the same application.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can always have two filters and establish authentication based on these

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it can be done.  You'll need to configure both OAuth2 and Form Login in
your
[WebSecurityConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.0/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/WebSecurityConfigurer.html)
and configure a custom login page.  You will also need to configure a
[PasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.0/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html?is-external=true)
and
[UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.0/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)
for Form Login and a
[OAuth2UserService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.0/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/userinfo/OAuth2UserService.html)
(and possibly a
[OidcUserService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.0/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/userinfo/OidcUserService.html))
for OAuth2 login.  The
[Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html)
implementation will correspond to the type of login.

`WebSecurityConfigurer.configure(HttpSecurity)`:

```java
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests(t -> t.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(t -> t.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .logout(t -> t.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                              .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll());
            ...
        }
```

Custom login page including form login and OAuth2 provider links:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <form th:object="${form}">
        <input type="email" th:name="username" th:placeholder="'E\'mail Address'"/>
        <label th:text="'E\'mail Address'"/>
        <input type="password" th:name="password" th:placeholder="'Password'"/>
        <label th:text="'Password'"/>
        <button type="submit" th:text="'Login'"/>
        <th:block th:if="${! oauth2.isEmpty()}">
          <hr/>
          <a th:each="client : ${oauth2}" th:href="@{/oauth2/authorization/{id}(id=${client.registrationId})}" th:text="${client.clientName}"/>
        </th:block>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p th:if="${param.error}">Invalid username and password.</p>
      <p th:if="${param.logout}">You have been logged out.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OAuth2 configuration:

```yaml
---
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            client-secret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        provider:
          google:
            user-name-attribute: email
```

This draws from my article at
https://blog.hcf.dev/article/2020-10-31-spring-boot-part-07 (source code
at
https://github.com/allen-ball/spring-boot-web-server/tree/trunk/part-07).