How can you login with Mircrosoft Entra ID or User Password using Spring Security?
I have setup a "Sign in with Azure AD" button but as an alternative to signing in with user + password. But when trying to access the /login/oauth2/code/ path I receive an Unauthorized response. How can I have both methods of login be acceptable instead of just user + password?
How can I have a custom login page with a "Sign in with Azure AD" Button? Either option should work for authenticating the user like below.
img:

SecurityConfig:
package com.example.AzureADTest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->{
           auth.requestMatchers("/get").fullyAuthenticated();
           auth.requestMatchers("/login/oauth2/**").permitAll();
        })
                .formLogin(formLogin ->
                        formLogin
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("u")
                .password("p")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}

Custom Login Page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login Screen</h1>
<div>
    <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Please login</legend>
            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">
                Invalid username and password
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                You have been logged out
            </div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Log In</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <button href="/login/oauth2/code/">Login with Azure AD</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Controller:
package com.example.AzureADTest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class Controllerz {

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String getTest(){
        return "get";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLogin(){
        return "login";
    }
}

Application.yml (ids replaced with XXXX)
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        enabled: true
        profile:
          tenant-id: XXXX
        credential:
          client-id: XXXX
          client-secret: XXXX
  application:
    name: AzureADTest

Current Dependencies:
    <name>AzureADTest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.12.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
    </properties>
        <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Attempted to permitAll() the base path for Microsoft Entra ID's login page but received Unauthorized error when clicked.

maybe this answer can help you, both oauth and user/password https://stackoverflow.com/a/67960030/3224238 and this example with both azure and google oauth https://stackoverflow.com/a/74517774/3224238

I have changed the application.yml file as follows and successfully logged in.
application.yml :
spring:
  application:
    name: AzureADTest
  thymeleaf:
    prefix: classpath:/templates/
    suffix: .html
  cloud:
    azure:
      profile:
        tenant-id: <tenant-ID>
      credential:
        client-id: <client-ID>
        client-secret: <client-secret>
    compatibility-verifier:
      enabled: false
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

SecurityConfig.java :
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers("/get").authenticated();
                auth.requestMatchers("/login", "/login/oauth2/**").permitAll();
            })
            .formLogin(formLogin ->
                formLogin
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
            );
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("u")
            .password("p")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}

pom.xml :
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I added the URL below in the app's Authentication URL as follows:
http://localhost:8080


Browser output :
I received the output below in the browser and successfully logged in using my username and password, as shown below.

Output :


@drocky Did you get a chance to look into the solution I provide?
